# In ASP.Net, what is the best way to store int in system.web.caching?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, int32

Currently, I have to convert `int` to `string` and store in cache, very complex

```
int test = 123;
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("key", test.ToString()); // to save the cache
test = Int32.Parse(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get("key").ToString()); // to get the cache
```

Is here a faster way without change type again and again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can store any kind of object in the cache. The method signature is:

```
Cache.Insert(string, object)
```

so, you don't need to convert to string before inserting. You will, however, need to cast when you retrieve from the cache:

```
int test = 123;
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("key", test); 
object cacheVal = HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get("key");
if(cacheVal != null)
{
    test = (int)cacheVal;
}
```

This will incur a boxing/unboxing penalty with primitive types, but considerably less so than going via string each time.

Comment: `test = (int)HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get("key");` gives error, Cannot convert type `string` to `int`, has to use `Parse`, and to use `Parse`, you have to use `.ToString()` first.

Comment: It looks like you didn't store an int in the first place. What is `typeof(HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get("key")).ToString()`?

Comment: you right. But I don't think I can directly do this, since cache maybe `null`, and `(int)null` gives error

Answer (score 1):

You could implement your own method that handles it so the calling code looks cleaner.

```
public void InsertIntIntoCache( string key, int value )
{
   HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert( key, value );
}

public int GetIntCacheValue( string key )
{
   return (int)HttpContext.Current.Cache[key];
}

int test = 123;
InsertIntIntoCache( "key", test );
test = GetIntCacheValue( "key" );
```